# Run PHP-Script through CLI and don't stop it when disconnecting SSH

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a droplet at digitalocean and want to run a php script through CLI (I connect via Putty). Unfortunately, it stops when I close my Putty-client.
Is it possible that it doesn't stop? At the moment I do a workaround with cron:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/admin/myscript.php
```

I remove the line as soon as the script has started.

Answer (score 1):

Use **screen** to run your program

```
screen php /var/www/admin/myscript.php
```

and then detach from the screen using CTRL+A d

You can use screen to run any number of programs by running screen command_you_want_to_run

and then detach from the screen

More about screen here http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

A gentle introduction to screen http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/